# Kivy textinput on_leave property

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I am trying to get a textinput that when the user leaves focus with a tab or click in another widget it will run a validation function that I Built for the widget. THe problem i found is that the textinput widget does not have on_leave property. I know I could use on_text_Validate but I want to be able to do it when the user press tab or clicks away.

Any ideas on how to bring the on_leave property to the text_input widget ?

I am using Kivy 1.9.2, Python 3, Windows 8 machine

Answer (score 1):

```
def on_focus(self, *args):
    if self.focus:
        'do something'            
    else:
        'do something'
```

try this i hope it helps,,